# What is the best way to solve this problem between dates and dataframes?

Tags: python, pandas, date, datetime

In this problem, you have two dataframes, one with the last price release, normally the present day. And in the other dataframe, we have all the launches.

The idea is that we can work with these two dataframes, in a way that the result is the result of the difference between the present day and the second most recent day of that price. Repeating the present day and ignoring the penultimate date. And the hardest part is that this difference needs to follow the periodicity pattern. So if the date type is Friday, the difference can only be from previous Fridays.

In a way that the lines are repeated, with the exception of the price which is not available.

**First Dataframe**:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
'Type': ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3'], 
'State': ['New York', 'Washington', 'Illinois'], 
'Date':['25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022'], 
'Price':['5.00','4.00','4.00'], 
'Type-Date':['Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)']}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_1

    Type     State      Date        Price   Name-Date
0   Product1 New York   25/03/2022  5.00    Friday (only)
1   Product2 Washington 25/03/2022  4.00    Friday (only)
2   Product3 Illinois   25/03/2022  4.00    Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
```

**Second Dataframe**:

```
data = {'Type': ['Product1', 'Product1', 'Product1','Product2','Product2','Product2','Product3','Product3','Product3'], 
'State': ['New York', 'New York','New York', 'Washington', 'Washington', 'Washington', 'Illinois', 'Illinois', 'Illinois'], 
'Date':['25/03/2022','04/03/2022','25/02/2022', '25/03/2022', '11/03/2022', '04/03/2022', '25/03/2022', '16/03/2022', '14/03/2022'], 
'Price':['5.00','4.00','4.00','4.00','3.00','2.00','4.00','3.00','4.00'], 
'Type-Date':['Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Friday (only)',
'Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)','Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)','Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)']}

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df_2

    Type     State      Date        Price   Type-Date
0   Product1 New York   25/03/2022  5.00    Friday (only)
1   Product1 New York   04/03/2022  4.00    Friday (only)
2   Product1 New York   25/02/2022  4.00    Friday (only)
3   Product2 Washington 25/03/2022  4.00    Friday (only)
4   Product2 Washington 11/03/2022  3.00    Friday (only)
5   Product2 Washington 04/03/2022  2.00    Friday (only)
6   Product3 Illinois   25/03/2022  4.00    Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
7   Product3 Illinois   16/03/2022  3.00    Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
8   Product3 Illinois   14/03/2022  4.00    Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
```

**Desired Results**

```
    Type     State      Date       Price  Type-Date
0   Product1 New York   25/03/2022 5.00   Friday (only)
1   Product1 New York   18/03/2022 NaN    Friday (only)
2   Product1 New York   11/03/2022 NaN    Friday (only)
3   Product2 Washington 25/03/2022 4.00   Friday (only)
4   Product2 Washington 18/03/2022 NaN    Friday (only)
5   Product3 Illinois   25/03/2022 4.00   Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
6   Product3 Illinois   23/03/2022 NaN    Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
7   Product3 Illinois   21/03/2022 NaN    Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
8   Product3 Illinois   18/03/2022 NaN    Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
```

Comment: It's unclear to me why the desired results has twice product 2, and four times product 3, while the input only has 3 times both products.

Comment: You mention the difference between the most recent price, and that of a previous time. I see 4.00 in the results, which is not a difference of any of the numbers in the input dataframes. Where does 4.00 come from then?

Comment: Note that 23/03/2022 is a Wednesday, not a Thursday (row 6 in the results). So is 16/03/2022 (row 7 in df_2). I guess Thursday has to be a Wednesday in Type-Date?

Comment: So you want the code to understand the days in Type-Date? That is, the code has to parse the names of the weekdays (ignoring the "(only)" part, I assume), and obtain the weekday from that, so that it can calculate previous dates?

Comment: Yea, I miss some values in the Desired Results, sorry guys. It's wednesday, not thursday and the price in product 1 is 5, not 4. But the idea is the same, is to take the second most recent date and take all those days between the two dates.  You can substitute Type-date values ​​for the days of the week if that makes it easier for the datetime library.

Comment: When I said difference between prices, it's actually difference between dates. Because each date represents a price. Sorry for the misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a lot here, which also means there are several possible circumstances that could arise that may or may not be anticipated in this answer. For example, what if the date in df_1 for a given Type is not found in df_2, or there are no entries in df_2 for a given Type, etc.

With that caveat, here is some code that produces the desired results specified in the question:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
'Type': ['Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3'], 
'State': ['New York', 'Washington', 'Illinois'], 
'Date':['25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022'], 
'Price':['5.00','4.00','4.00'], 
'Type-Date':['Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)']}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data)

data = {'Type': ['Product1', 'Product1', 'Product1','Product2','Product2','Product2','Product3','Product3','Product3'], 
'State': ['New York', 'New York','New York', 'Washington', 'Washington', 'Washington', 'Illinois', 'Illinois', 'Illinois'], 
'Date':['25/03/2022','04/03/2022','25/02/2022', '25/03/2022', '11/03/2022', '04/03/2022', '25/03/2022', '16/03/2022', '14/03/2022'], 
'Price':['5.00','4.00','4.00','4.00','3.00','2.00','4.00','3.00','4.00'], 
'Type-Date':['Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Friday (only)',
'Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)','Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)','Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)']}

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data)

'''
Objective:
Create a dataframe which for each Type contains:
- today's Date and Price from df_1
- prior Date values with Price of NaN going back in time according to the Type's corresponding Type-Date value, back to but not including the penultimate date for which a price is available in df_2
'''

dayStrToInt = {'Monday':0,'Tuesday':1,'Wednesday':2,'Thursday':3,'Friday':4,'Saturday':5,'Sunday':6}
freqByType = {}
def setFreqByType(row):
    weekdays = [s.strip() for s in row['Type-Date'].replace('(only)', '').split(',')]
    if not weekdays:
        raise ValueError(f"No weekdays found in Type-Date {repr(row['Type-Date'])}")
    days = []
    for w in weekdays:
        if w not in dayStrToInt:
            raise ValueError(f'Bad day-of-week string {w}')
        days.append(dayStrToInt[w])
    freqByType[row['Type']] = days
import datetime
datePriceListByType = []
def compileDatePriceByType(row):
    curType = row['Type']
    curDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    allDates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%d/%m/%Y').date() for dateStr in df_2[df_2['Type']==row['Type']]['Date']]
    allDateStrs = [dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') for dt in allDates]
    minDate = min(allDates)
    newDates = [curDate]
    dt = curDate
    days = freqByType[curType]
    while dt > minDate:
        curWD = dt.weekday()
        nextWD = curWD
        while nextWD not in days:
            nextWD = (nextWD - 1) % 7
        iWD = (days.index(nextWD) - (1 if nextWD == curWD else 0)) % len(days)
        dt -= datetime.timedelta(days=(curWD - days[iWD]) % 7 if curWD != days[iWD] else 7)
        if dt in allDates:
            break
        if dt > minDate:
            newDates.append(dt)
    datePrice = [[dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') for dt in newDates], [row['Price']] + [np.nan]*(len(newDates) - 1)]
    datePriceListByType.append(datePrice)

df_1.apply(setFreqByType, axis=1)
df_1.apply(compileDatePriceByType, axis=1)
df_result = df_1
df_result[['Date', 'Price']] = pd.DataFrame(datePriceListByType, columns=['Date', 'Price'])
df_result = df_result.explode(['Date', 'Price'], ignore_index=True)
print(df_result)
```

Output:

```
       Type       State        Date Price                         Type-Date
0  Product1    New York  25/03/2022  5.00                     Friday (only)
1  Product1    New York  18/03/2022   NaN                     Friday (only)
2  Product1    New York  11/03/2022   NaN                     Friday (only)
3  Product2  Washington  25/03/2022  4.00                     Friday (only)
4  Product2  Washington  18/03/2022   NaN                     Friday (only)
5  Product3    Illinois  25/03/2022  4.00  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
6  Product3    Illinois  23/03/2022   NaN  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
7  Product3    Illinois  21/03/2022   NaN  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
8  Product3    Illinois  18/03/2022   NaN  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
```

**UPDATE:** Having the key be (Type, Region) instead of just Type.

If there is a need to have the Type-Date (i.e., the weekly schedule) vary based on a multi-column key such as (Type, Region), this can be achieved as well. While it is possible to generalize this based on a list of key columns, I will just share an example that hardcodes the two columns Type and Region:

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {
'Type': ['Product1', 'Product1', 'Product2', 'Product3'], 
'Region': ['Northeast', 'Southeast', 'Northwest', 'Midwest'], 
'State': ['New York', 'Florida', 'Washington', 'Illinois'], 
'Date':['25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022','25/03/2022'], 
'Price':['5.00','4.50','4.00','4.00'], 
'Type-Date':['Friday (only)','Tuesday, Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)']}

df_1 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(f"df_1\n{df_1}")

data = {'Type': ['Product1', 'Product1', 'Product1','Product1', 'Product1', 'Product1','Product2','Product2','Product2','Product3','Product3','Product3'], 
'Region': ['Northeast', 'Northeast', 'Northeast', 'Southeast', 'Southeast', 'Southeast', 'Northwest', 'Northwest', 'Northwest', 'Midwest', 'Midwest', 'Midwest'], 
'State': ['New York', 'New York','New York', 'Florida', 'Florida', 'Florida', 'Washington', 'Washington', 'Washington', 'Illinois', 'Illinois', 'Illinois'], 
'Date':['25/03/2022','04/03/2022','25/02/2022', '25/03/2022','04/03/2022','25/02/2022', '25/03/2022', '11/03/2022', '04/03/2022', '25/03/2022', '16/03/2022', '14/03/2022'], 
'Price':['5.00','4.00','4.00','4.50','4.25','4.10','4.00','3.00','2.00','4.00','3.00','4.00'], 
'Type-Date':['Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Tuesday, Friday (only)','Tuesday, Friday (only)','Tuesday, Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Friday (only)','Friday (only)',
'Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)','Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)','Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)']}

df_2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(f"df_2\n{df_2}")

'''
Objective:
Create a dataframe which for each (Type, Region) pair contains:
- today's Date and Price from df_1
- prior Date values with Price of NaN going back in time according to the (Type, Region) pair's corresponding Type-Date value, back to but not including the penultimate date for which a price is available in df_2
'''

dayStrToInt = {'Monday':0,'Tuesday':1,'Wednesday':2,'Thursday':3,'Friday':4,'Saturday':5,'Sunday':6}
freqByTypeRegion = {}
def setFreqByTypeRegion(row):
    weekdays = [s.strip() for s in row['Type-Date'].replace('(only)', '').split(',')]
    if not weekdays:
        raise ValueError(f"No weekdays found in Type-Date {repr(row['Type-Date'])}")
    days = []
    for w in weekdays:
        if w not in dayStrToInt:
            raise ValueError(f'Bad day-of-week string {w}')
        days.append(dayStrToInt[w])
    freqByTypeRegion[(row['Type'], row['Region'])] = days
import datetime
datePriceListByTypeRegion = []
def compileDatePriceByTypeRegion(row):
    curTypeRegion = (row['Type'], row['Region'])
    curDate = datetime.datetime.strptime(row['Date'], '%d/%m/%Y').date()
    allDates = [datetime.datetime.strptime(dateStr, '%d/%m/%Y').date() for dateStr in df_2[(df_2['Type']==row['Type']) & (df_2['Region']==row['Region'])]['Date']]
    allDateStrs = [dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') for dt in allDates]
    minDate = min(allDates)
    newDates = [curDate]
    dt = curDate
    days = freqByTypeRegion[curTypeRegion]
    while dt > minDate:
        curWD = dt.weekday()
        nextWD = curWD
        while nextWD not in days:
            nextWD = (nextWD - 1) % 7
        iWD = (days.index(nextWD) - (1 if nextWD == curWD else 0)) % len(days)
        dt -= datetime.timedelta(days=(curWD - days[iWD]) % 7 if curWD != days[iWD] else 7)
        if dt in allDates:
            break
        if dt > minDate:
            newDates.append(dt)
    datePrice = [[dt.strftime('%d/%m/%Y') for dt in newDates], [row['Price']] + [np.nan]*(len(newDates) - 1)]
    datePriceListByTypeRegion.append(datePrice)

df_1.apply(setFreqByTypeRegion, axis=1)
df_1.apply(compileDatePriceByTypeRegion, axis=1)
df_result = df_1
df_result[['Date', 'Price']] = pd.DataFrame(datePriceListByTypeRegion, columns=['Date', 'Price'])
df_result = df_result.explode(['Date', 'Price'], ignore_index=True)
print(f"df_result\n{df_result}")
```

Output:

```
df_1
       Type     Region       State        Date Price                         Type-Date
0  Product1  Northeast    New York  25/03/2022  5.00                     Friday (only)
1  Product1  Southeast     Florida  25/03/2022  4.50            Tuesday, Friday (only)
2  Product2  Northwest  Washington  25/03/2022  4.00                     Friday (only)
3  Product3    Midwest    Illinois  25/03/2022  4.00  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
df_2
        Type     Region       State        Date Price                         Type-Date
0   Product1  Northeast    New York  25/03/2022  5.00                     Friday (only)
1   Product1  Northeast    New York  04/03/2022  4.00                     Friday (only)
2   Product1  Northeast    New York  25/02/2022  4.00                     Friday (only)
3   Product1  Southeast     Florida  25/03/2022  4.50            Tuesday, Friday (only)
4   Product1  Southeast     Florida  04/03/2022  4.25            Tuesday, Friday (only)
5   Product1  Southeast     Florida  25/02/2022  4.10            Tuesday, Friday (only)
6   Product2  Northwest  Washington  25/03/2022  4.00                     Friday (only)
7   Product2  Northwest  Washington  11/03/2022  3.00                     Friday (only)
8   Product2  Northwest  Washington  04/03/2022  2.00                     Friday (only)
9   Product3    Midwest    Illinois  25/03/2022  4.00  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
10  Product3    Midwest    Illinois  16/03/2022  3.00  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
11  Product3    Midwest    Illinois  14/03/2022  4.00  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
df_result
        Type     Region       State        Date Price                         Type-Date
0   Product1  Northeast    New York  25/03/2022  5.00                     Friday (only)
1   Product1  Northeast    New York  18/03/2022   NaN                     Friday (only)
2   Product1  Northeast    New York  11/03/2022   NaN                     Friday (only)
3   Product1  Southeast     Florida  25/03/2022  4.50            Tuesday, Friday (only)
4   Product1  Southeast     Florida  22/03/2022   NaN            Tuesday, Friday (only)
5   Product1  Southeast     Florida  18/03/2022   NaN            Tuesday, Friday (only)
6   Product1  Southeast     Florida  15/03/2022   NaN            Tuesday, Friday (only)
7   Product1  Southeast     Florida  11/03/2022   NaN            Tuesday, Friday (only)
8   Product1  Southeast     Florida  08/03/2022   NaN            Tuesday, Friday (only)
9   Product2  Northwest  Washington  25/03/2022  4.00                     Friday (only)
10  Product2  Northwest  Washington  18/03/2022   NaN                     Friday (only)
11  Product3    Midwest    Illinois  25/03/2022  4.00  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
12  Product3    Midwest    Illinois  23/03/2022   NaN  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
13  Product3    Midwest    Illinois  21/03/2022   NaN  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
14  Product3    Midwest    Illinois  18/03/2022   NaN  Monday, Wednesday, Friday (only)
```

Comment: This is absolutely amazing! Thank you very much.

Just one thing, if I want more columns to be considered, besides the product, to define each of the dates, like region, would I be able to?

Comment: @Eliãn Yes, you can use a Type-Date weekly schedule based on a multi-column key like (Type, Region) instead of just based on Type. Please see my updated answer for an example.

Comment: Everything is perfect, already solves all my problems here. Thank you so much man.